# disable onscroll event of the icefaces datatable

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I used an ice:dataTable component to display data, somehow there was a default onscroll event in the target div which doesn't make any sense to me and it had brought some positioning problems to other float elements within the page. I want to disable this action, but I didn't find any approach to control this.

It called the function below:

```
var input = document.getElementById('targetId'); clearTimeout(ice.pid); 
ice.pid = setTimeout(function() { 
    input.value =   
    document.getElementById('targetId_scroll').scrollTop;    
    window.iceSubmitPartial(null, input, event); 
}, 400);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ICEFaces and as we upgraded the JSF and ICEFaces versions the best solution was to change the tags: 
**ice:dataTable** tag to **ace:dataTable** and the columns inside from **ice:column** to **ace:column**.

But, if you didn't upgrade ICEFaces version, I guess you could use a JavaScript or jQuery in some point of your code removing the onscroll attribute, like:

```
document._getElementsByXPath("//div[contains(@onscroll,'scroll')]")[0].removeAttribute("onscroll")
```

*This one isn't a good one, just a example, cause you can remove scroll from other tables.*

```
jQuery('.myClass div[id$="_scroll"]')[0].removeAttribute("onscroll")
```